# Creating subset of dataset based on multiple condition in r

Tags: r

I want to extract the past 3 weeks' data for each `household_id`, `channel` combination. These past 3 weeks will be calculated from `mala_fide_week` and `mala_fide_year` and it will be less than that for each `household_id` and `channel` combination.

Below is the dataset:

[image]

for e.g. `Household_id` 100 for channel A: the `mala_fide_week` is 42 and `mala_fide_year` 2021. So past three records will be less than week 42 of the year 2021. This will be calculated from the `week` and `year` columns.

For the `Household_id` 100 and `channel` B combination, there are only two records much less than `mala_fide_week` and `mala_fide_year`.

For `Household_id` 101 and `channel` C, there are two years involved in 2019 and 2020.

The final dataset will be as below

[image]

`Household_id` 102 is not considered as week and year is greater than `mala_fide_week` and `mala_fide_year`.

I am trying multiple options but not getting through. Any help is much appreciated!

sample dataset:

```
 data <- data.frame(Household_id = 
 c(100,100,100,100,100,100,101,101,101,101,102,102),
               channel = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","c","C","D","D"),
               duration = c(12,34,567,67,34,67,98,23,56,89,73,76),
               mala_fide_week = c(42,42,42,42,42,42,5,5,5,5,30,30),
               mala_fide_year =c(2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2020,2020,2020,2020,2021,2021),
               week =c(36,37,38,39,22,23,51,52,1,2,38,39),
               year = c(2021,2021,2021,2021,2020,2020,2019,2019,2020,2020,2021,2021))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you first need to obtain the absolute number of weeks `week + year * 52`, then filter accordingly. `slice_tail` gets the last three rows of each group.

```r
library(dplyr)

data |>
  filter(week + 52*year <= mala_fide_week + 52 *mala_fide_year) |>
  group_by(Household_id, channel)  |>
  arrange(year, week, .by_group = TRUE) |>
  slice_tail(n = 3)

# A tibble: 8 x 7
# Groups:   Household_id, channel [3]
  Household_id channel duration mala_fide_week mala_fide_year  week  year
         <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1          100 A             34             42           2021    37  2021
2          100 A            567             42           2021    38  2021
3          100 A             67             42           2021    39  2021
4          100 B             34             42           2021    22  2020
5          100 B             67             42           2021    23  2020
6          101 C             23              5           2020    52  2019
7          101 C             56              5           2020     1  2020
8          101 C             89              5           2020     2  2020
```

Comment: this is very much on the target. For the sake of others to learn I had to update my r from 3.6 to 4.1.2 and dplyr also to get |> and slice_tail work. Thanks a ton